# Price quote calculation

Tags: javascript, next.js

I am developing an instant quote calculator for a Next.js project. Using the below logic I am able to calculate price using a fixed price point of 0.05.

```
'use client';

import { useState } from 'react';
import styles from '../styles';
import { allLanguages } from '../constants';

const QuoteContainer = () => {
  const [wordCount, setWordCount] = useState('');
  const [sourceLanguage, setSourceLanguage] = useState('');
  const [targetLanguage, setTargetLanguage] = useState('');
  const [totalPrice, setTotalPrice] = useState('');
  const handleWordCountChange = (event) => {
    setWordCount(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSourceLanguageChange = (event) => {
    setSourceLanguage(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleTargetLanguageChange = (event) => {
    setTargetLanguage(event.target.value);
  };
 

  const handleCalculatePrice = () => {
    const price = Number(wordCount) * 0.05;
    setTotalPrice(price.toFixed(2));
   
  };
  return (
    <section className={`${styles.paddings} mt-0`} id="quote">
      <div className="theme-neon relative bg-skin-fill max-w-6xl mt-12 mx-auto overflow-hidden sm:rounded-2xl">
        <img className="absolute inset-0 h-full w-full object-cover opacity-30" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1613217784112-e0e197be6a0b?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1600&q=80&sat=-100" alt="People working on laptops" />
        <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-gradient-to-br from-skin-hue via-skin-hue to-transparent opacity-90" />
        <div className="relative max-w-2xl mx-auto text-center py-16 px-4 sm:py-20 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
          <h2 className="text-3xl font-extrabold text-skin-base sm:text-4xl">
            <span className="block">Professional translations made easy.</span>
          </h2>
          <p className="mt-4 text-md leading-6 text-skin-muted">
            <span className="font-extrabold text-gray-300" /> In a few clicks, input your order and receive your quote right away.
          </p>
          <div className="flex flex-row w-full items-center justify-between">
            <div className="flex flex-col w-full mt-6 items-center justify-center text-left">
              <div className="flex flex-row w-full">
                <div className="mt-12 flex flex-col w-full">
                  <div className="flex flex-row">
                    <div className="w-full mr-4 ml-0">
                      <label htmlFor="InstantQuoteSourceLanguages" className="block mb-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Source Language</label>
                      <div className="flex relative z-[1]">

                        <select
                          required id="InstantQuoteSourceLanguages"
                          className="block w-full px-4 py-3 text-base text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                          value={sourceLanguage}
                          onChange={handleSourceLanguageChange}
                        >
                          <option value="" disabled>From</option>
                          {allLanguages
                          && allLanguages.map((language) => (
                            <option
                              key={`${language.name}-matrix`}
                              value={[language.group.toString(), language.name]}
                            >
                              {language.name}
                            </option>
                          ))}
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="w-full mr-4 ml-0 ">
                      <label htmlFor="InstantQuoteTargetLanguages" className="block mb-2 text-base font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Target Language</label>
                      <div className="flex relative z-[1]">
                        <select
                          required id="InstantQuoteTargetLanguages"
                          className="block w-full px-4 py-3 text-base text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                          value={targetLanguage}
                          onChange={handleTargetLanguageChange}
                        >
                          <option value="" disabled>To</option>
                          {allLanguages
                          && allLanguages.map((language) => (
                            <option
                              key={language.name}
                              value={[language.group.toString(), language.name]}
                            >
                              {language.name}
                            </option>
                          ))}
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div className="relative flex flex-col ml-0 mt-4 w-full self-end min-w-0">
                    <label htmlFor="InstantQuoteWordCount" className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 dark:text-white">Word count</label>
                    <input
                      id="InstantQuoteWordCount"
                      value={wordCount}
                      onChange={handleWordCountChange}
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="write the word count in numbers"
                      className="bg-gray-50 border border-gray-300 text-gray-900 text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 block w-full p-2.5 dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="realatie flex flex-col flex-[1] self-end min-w-0 mx-4 my-0">

                    <input
                      type="submit"
                      className="text-skin-inverted bg-skin-button-accent hover:bg-skin-button-accent-hover flex items-center justify-center px-4 py-3 mt-4 border border-transparent text-base font-medium rounded-md shadow-sm sm:px-8"
                      value="Show prices"
                      onClick={handleCalculatePrice}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div className="relative flex-[1] flex flex-col items-center  mt-6 pt-2 pb-6 px-4">
                {totalPrice && (

                <div className="flex flex-col max-w-md p-6 space-y-4 divide-y sm:w-96 sm:p-10 divide-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-900 dark:text-gray-100">
                  <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold">Quote Summary</h2>
                  <ul className="flex flex-col pt-4 space-y-2">
                    <li className="flex items-start justify-between">
                      <h3>Language:
                        <span className="text-sm dark:text-violet-400">Source</span>
                      </h3>
                      <div className="text-right">
                        <span className="block">{sourceLanguage}</span>

                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li className="flex items-start justify-between">
                      <h3>Language:
                        <span className="text-sm dark:text-violet-400">Target</span>
                      </h3>
                      <div className="text-right">
                        <span className="block">{targetLanguage}</span>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                    <li className="flex items-start justify-between">
                      <h3>Word Count
                        <span className="text-sm dark:text-violet-400">#</span>
                      </h3>
                      <div className="text-right">
                        <span className="block">{wordCount}</span>

                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div className="pt-4 space-y-2">
                    <div className="flex justify-between">
                      <span>Rate</span>
                      <span>$0.50</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="flex items-center space-x-2 text-xs">
                      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" className="w-3 h-3 mt-1 fill-current dark:text-violet-400">
                        <path d="M485.887,263.261,248,25.373A31.791,31.791,0,0,0,225.373,16H64A48.055,48.055,0,0,0,16,64V225.078A32.115,32.115,0,0,0,26.091,248.4L279.152,486.125a23.815,23.815,0,0,0,16.41,6.51q.447,0,.9-.017a23.828,23.828,0,0,0,16.79-7.734L486.581,296.479A23.941,23.941,0,0,0,485.887,263.261ZM295.171,457.269,48,225.078V64A16.019,16.019,0,0,1,64,48H225.373L457.834,280.462Z" />
                        <path d="M148,96a52,52,0,1,0,52,52A52.059,52.059,0,0,0,148,96Zm0,72a20,20,0,1,1,20-20A20.023,20.023,0,0,1,148,168Z" />
                      </svg>
                      <span className="dark:text-gray-400">Order until August 31, 2023, get 20% off</span>
                    </div>
                    <div className="space-y-6">
                      <div className="flex justify-between">
                        <span>Total</span>
                        <span className="font-semibold">{totalPrice}</span>
                      </div>
                      <button type="button" className="w-full py-2 font-semibold border rounded text-skin-inverted bg-skin-button-accent hover:bg-skin-button-accent-hover">Order Now</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                )}

              </div>
              <div className="text-sm leading-[26px] mt-[30px]">
                <span className="text-lg leading-5 font-medium text-blue-700 align-middle m-0 px-3 py-1.5 rounded-2xl bg-skin-button-accent;">Pay after delivery</span> We trust you: feel free to pay within 5 days from delivery via bank transfer, credit card, or PayPal.  <a href="frequently-asked-questions#payments">Learn more</a>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

  );
};

export default QuoteContainer;
```

However, I would like to make variations of pricing on different language groups. for Example I would like to apply group 1 languages a price rate of 0.05, group 2: 0.06 and group 3: 0.07 and group 4: 0.08 as it is displayed as follows.

```
const allLanguages = [
  { name: 'Spanish (ES)', group: 1},
  { name: 'Spanish (LATAM)', group: 2 },
  { name: 'US English', group: 3},
  { name: 'English UK', group: 4},
];
```

How can I incorporate the above requirement in my previous working logic?

Answer (score 0):

To account for the variation in prices for different language groups, you can create a function called `getPricePerWord` then you can use this function to account for the language group.

```
const allLanguages = [
  { name: 'Spanish (ES)', group: 1},
  { name: 'Spanish (LATAM)', group: 2 },
  { name: 'US English', group: 3},
  { name: 'English UK', group: 4},
];

function getPricePerWord(language) {
  let pricePerWord = 0.05;
  switch(language.group) {
    case 1:
      pricePerWord = 0.05;
      break;
    case 2:
      pricePerWord = 0.06;
      break;
    case 3:
      pricePerWord = 0.07;
      break;
    case 4:
      pricePerWord = 0.08;
      break;
    default:
      pricePerWord = 0.05;
  }
  return pricePerWord;
}
```

Then you can implement this function within the `calculatePrice` function like so retrieving the price for specific languages. Keep in mind that you have to make sure you also send the language to the `calculatePrice` function.

```
function calculatePrice(words, language) {
  const pricePerWord = getPricePerWord(language);
  const totalPrice = words * pricePerWord;
  return totalPrice;
}
```